# Create table on new page from dynamic table

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, jsp

I need a help. I have a dynamic table:

```
while (result.next()) {
    out.write("<tr>");
    for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++) {
        out.write("<td>" + result.getString(i) + "</td>");
    }
    out.write("</tr>");
}
```

Clicking on the row of this table it needs to open new page or window with table 1 column has data from the row. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Attach an event to each tr in the table.

```
while (result.next()) {
    out.write("<tr class="table-row">");
    for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++) {
        out.write("<td>" + result.getString(i) + "</td>");
    }
    out.write("</tr>");
}

$('.table-row').on('click', function(){
    var values_array = [];
    var td_values = "";
    var tr_children = $(this).find('td').each (function() {
         values_array.push($(this).html());
    });

    $.each(values_array, function(value){
       td_values += "value1="+ value +"&";
    });

    // create a query string with the values and send to a new page like this
    // you can concatenate the values to the 
    window.location.replace("http://page?"+td_values);
});
```

Comment: Can I do it use javascript?

Comment: I think will be harder for you to do it only with JavaScript.